# Delete text every n seconds in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

I have a .txt file that updates every five seconds.

```
22:37:03

Some text 1

22:37:08

Some text 2

Some text 3

22:37:13

Some text 4
```

I have a program that reads this data from the Start of the file, which I'd like to be as up to date as possible (to within 5 seconds if possible).

If I read the file directly with the program it starts from the earliest entry, which may be up to two hours behind (depending on when I started writing the file).

Is there a command I could add to a batch file that would delete any data that was say 8 seconds older than the current system time?

I already run a command that deletes the first 2 lines every 5 seconds, but the number of lines under the time stamp vary.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, there is no txt file which is able to update itself ;-) So a process is appending to the file and if two processes concur updating a file (if even possible) the risc of file locks or lost updates exist.

Comment: I see your point. The file is created by a program, a log as it were. A different program then reads this log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42253025.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=:" %%p IN ("%%a") DO (
  IF "%%r"=="" (>>"%outfile%" ECHO %%a) ELSE (>"%outfile%" ECHO %%a)
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42253025.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Assuming `filename1` is your logfile, then this code will read that file and create a new file containing that section of the logfile from the final timestamp onwards.

I'm making a few assumptions. First, you don't want empty lines and second that any lines that contain two or more colons are timestamp lines. I haven't tested for the effects of "poison characters" (those symbols with a special meaning to `cmd` like `!%^&><|`)

If the procedure takes too long (such that it still has hold of the file when the generator program wants to perform the next write) then perhaps copying your log to a completely separate file then using this procedure on the copy may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

if the file gets updated every 5 seconds and you want to show anything younger than 8 seconds, then you obviously want the last timestamp and following line(s):

```
@echo off
REM get LineNo of last TimeStamp (subtract one for future use)
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^[ 012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$" test.txt') do set /a LastStart=%%a-1
REM show, starting with the found LineNo
more +%LastStart% test.txt
```

(preserves any empty line(s), works even with "poison characters")